# Does the volatile qualifier matter in this case?

Tags: c++, c, volatile

I saw a code sample demonstrating the usage of the `volatile` qualifier in the answer of the question [C++ volatile member functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826719/c-volatile-member-functions), quoted as below:

```
volatile int x;

int DoSomething() {
    x = 1;
    DoSomeOtherStuff();
    return x+1; // Don't just return 2 because we stored a 1 in x.  
                // Check to get its current value
}
```

I don't know if the `volatile` qualifier makes any difference in the above code.  `x` is a global variable and there is a function call between the write and read on `x`, and we only read `x` for once.  Shouldn't the compiler perform a real read on `x` (even it's not `volatile`)?

I think it's different from the following case:

```
volatile int x;

int DoSomething() {
    x = 1;
    while (x != 1)
        break;
}
```

In this case, we repeatedly read `x` immediately after a write to `x`, so `volatile` is necessary to get the up-to-date value of `x` written by other threads.

I'm not very confident on my understanding of these code samples, please correct me if I'm wrong.

EDIT (respond to comments): I'm sorry I didn't make my question clear. As for the first code snippet, I'm questioning whether the code is a valid example for the **possible** usage of `volatile` (not the **guaranteed** usage of volatile). I just want to know, without `volatile`, whether it's guaranteed that any possible change to `x` in `DoSomeOtherStuff()` can be reflected in `return x+1`, assuming there's no multi-threading or other non-trivial things like memory mapped IO.  Cause if it is guaranteed to work without `volatile`, then the example is way off relevant, not to even mention the platform-dependent nature of `volatile` as some comments pointed out. But if it's not guaranteed, then I'm afraid some of my existing code may not work as I expected.
(I probably shouldn't have put the second code snippet at all.)

Comment: The C++ standard guarantees essentially nothing about the `volatile` keyword. (Try a search for "volatile is uselesss", which it is, if you are talking about portable multi-threaded programming.) So the behavior is entirely platform dependent. Please add a tag and/or update your question to indicate which compiler you mean.

Comment: This is a good explanation on how volatile actually can be quite useful, exactly for multi-threaded programming: http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/volatile-the-multithreaded-programmers-b/184403766

Comment: @MikeC: That article is making assumptions about the semantics of `volatile` in multithreaded programs that are nowhere found in the C specification. If a particular compiler implementation happens to make `volatile` mean "introduces a memory barrier" or whatever is necessary to make a variable "thread safe" (whatever *that* means), that is an unportable and implementation-defined usage of the keyword. A better article to point people at is as Nemo suggests: http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2007/11/30/volatile-almost-useless-for-multi-threaded-programming/.

Comment: @MikeC: The Herb Sutter article linked to by Dusty Campbell's answer is also good. Herb knows what he is talking about.

Comment: @Nemo It's not quite that bad.  C++ makes it clear that `volatile` is part of the type system, and Andrei Alexandrescu found a way to exploit that for thread safety.  The _intent_ is also very clear; it's just that there's no way of expressing it exactly in standardese.  (Of course, the _semantics_ of `volatile` are irrelevant with regards to multi-threading.)

Comment: @EricLippert Except that the Intel article and Herb's contradict one another for some of the details.  Where they disagree, the Intel article is correct.

Comment: @JamesKanze: In particular, Herb is assuming the semantics of `volatile` in Visual Studio, which can be used to implement (e.g.) double-checked locking. But the standard C++11 atomic operations, memory barriers, etc. are more portable and (when used correctly) more efficient, so there really is no use for `volatile` in modern C++. The only exception is totally platform-specific things like accessing hardware registers. (Although I suppose I should look at Alexandrescu's examples...)

Comment: @JamesKanze: Good point, thanks for that clarification.

Comment: @Nemo and other folks: Thank you very much for redirecting me to lots of useful stuffs.  I'm sorry I didn't make my question clear.  As for the first code snippet, I'm questioning whether the code is a valid example for the **possible** usage of `volatile` (not the **guaranteed** usage of `volatile`).  I just want to know, without `volatile`, whether it's guaranteed that any possible change to `x` in `DoSomeOtherStuff()` can be reflected in `return x+1`, assuming there's no multi-threading or other non-trivial things like memory mapped IO.

Comment: (cont.) Cause if it is guaranteed to work without `volatile`, then the example is way off relevant, not to even mention the platform-dependent nature of `volatile` as you guys pointed out.  But if it's not guaranteed, then I'm afraid some of my existing code may not work as I expected.

Comment: @Nemo I don't think he is.  For one, the article is from 2009; I know that Herb and others discussed many of the issues of `volatile` at the committee meeting in Berlin, before that, and that Herb was aware of the differences between what the standard requires, and what Microsoft was going to do.  And the C++ `volatile` that he describes is _not_ the Microsoft `volatile` at the time (which was closer to the Java `volatile`).  Globally, his points were well taken, but he still ascribed more constraints on the standard volatile than it has.

Comment: @Nemo The standard atomic types were introduced precisely because `volatile` didn't do the job.

Comment: @goodbyeera A compiler cannot assume that `DoSomeOtherStuff()` does not modify `x`, with or without `volatile`.  The effect of `volatile` here is that even if the compiler can see into `DoSomeOtherStuff()`, and determine that the C++ code doesn't modify `x`, it cannot assume that `x` is unmodified.

Answer (score 3):

The `volatile` qualifier never makes a difference in the meaning
of the code itself.  Unless the compiler can prove that 
`DoSomeOtherStuff()` doesn't modify `x`, it must reread `x`
regardless, `volatile` or no.  For `volatile` to be relevant,
`x` would have to be something like memory mapped IO, which
might change outside the program.  If we imagine that it is 
a register which is incremented every microsecond, for example:

```
int
MeasureExecutionTime()
{
    x = 0;
    DoSomeOtherStuff();
    return x;
}
```

would return the amount of time used in `DoSomeOtherStuff`; the
compiler would be required to reload it, even if it inlined
`DoSomeOtherStuff`, and saw that it never modified `x`.

Of course, on a typical desktop machine, there probably isn't
any memory mapped IO, and if there is, it's in protected memory,
where you cannot access it.  And a lot of compilers don't really
generate the code necessary to make it work correctly anyway.
So for general purpose applications on such machines, there's
really no sense in every using `volatile`.

EDIT:

Concerning your second code snippet: as usually implemented,
`volatile` does not guarantee that you get an up-to-date copy of
`x`.  Arguably, this is not conform with the intent of
`volatile`, but it is the way g++, Sun CC, and at least some
versions of VC++ work.  The compilers will issue a load
instruction to read `x` each time in the loop, but the hardware
may find the value already in the pipeline, and not propagate
that read request out to the memory bus.  In order to guarantee
a new read, the compiler would have to insert a fence or
a membar instruction.

Perhaps more importantly (since sooner or later, something will
happen so that the value won't be in the pipeline), this looping
mechanism will be used to wait until other values written in the
other thread have stabilized.  Except that volatile has no
effect on when the reads and writes of other variables occur.

To understand `volatile`, it's important to understand the
intent with which it was introduced.  When it was introduced,
memory pipelines and such were unknown, and the (C) standard
ignored threading (or multiple processes with shared memory).
The intent of `volatile` was to allow support of memory mapped
IO, where writing to an address had external consequences, and
successive reads wouldn't always read the same thing.  There was
never any intent that other variables in the code would be
synchronized.  When communicating between threads, it's normally
the *order* of reads and writes, to all shared variables, which
is important.  If I do something like:

```
globalPointer = new Xxx;
```

and other threads can access `globalPointer`, it's important
that all of the writes in the constructor of `Xxx` have become
visible before the change in the value of `globalPointer`
occurs.  For this to occur, not only would `globalPointer` have
to be `volatile`, but also all of the members of `Xxx`, and any
variables member functions of `Xxx` might use, or any data
accessible through a pointer in `Xxx`.  This simply isn't
reasonable; you would very soon end up with everything in the
program `volatile`.  And even then, it would also require that
compilers implement `volatile` correctly, isserting fence or
membar instructions around each access.  (FWIW: a fence or
a membar instruction can multiply time it takes for a memory
access by a factor of 10 or more.)

The solution here is not volatile, but to make accesses to the
pointer (and only accesses to the pointer) atomic, using the
`atomic_load` and `atomic_store` primitives added to C++11.
These primitives do cause the necessary fence or membar
instructions to be used; they also tell the compiler not to move
any memory access accross them.  So that using `atomic_load` to
set the pointer, above, will cause all preceding memory writes
to be visible to other threads before the write to the pointer
becomes visible (on the condition that the reading thread uses
`atomic_read`, of course—`atomic_write` ensures that all
previous writes are available in the "common" memory of all of
the threads, and `atomic_read` ensures that all following reads
will go to the "common" memory, and not pick up some value
already in the pipeline).

Answer (score 0):

A compiler *can* have some information about `DoSomeOtherStuff()` function. For example:

```
static int DoSomeOtherStuff()
{
    return 42;
}

volatile int x;

int DoSomething() {
  x = 1;
  DoSomeOtherStuff();
  return x+1; // Don't just return 2 because we stored a 1 in x.
  // Check to get its current value
}
```

GCC with `-O3` option completely removes the call of `DoSomeOtherStuff()` function (and its body as well) but still reloads `x` to return `x+1` in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an existing SO question about volatile:
[What is the use of volatile keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5190091/what-is-the-use-of-volatile-keyword)

With just the first code snippet you are right, there is no obvious reason to have x declared volatile.  However, if you understand what the keyword is supposed to be used for you could reason that x is volatile because there is something outside this code, which may change it's value.  For example the memory maybe attached to some other hardware or written to by another program.  Therefore, the programmer is instructing the compiler that it cannot see all the possible ways for the value of x to change. And so the compiler may not be able to optimize the code in certain ways.

The second code snippet in and of itself does not require the volatile keyword.  Volatile is used as a compiler hint stating that the memory could change by forces outside the current program.  It should not be used for thread communication.  There are new C++ types that should be used for those situations.

I recommend reading [this article](http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/volatile-vs-volatile/212701484) by Herb Sutter as well as [this talk](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-atomic-Weapons-1-of-2).

Answer (score 0):

The only way to really be sure here is to examine the assembly code generated for your target platform. If volatile is performing the way you intend, any read of the variable x will be accomplished via a load from memory.

Comment: From what memory?  On a lot of machines, reads and such are pipelined, so that without a special fence or membar instruction, the hardware might not do an external read, even if the compiler generated a load instruction.