# Why do all the member functions in std::atomic appear both with and without volatile?

Tags: c++, c++11, volatile

I noticed that most member functions of `std::atomic<T>` types are declared twice, once with the `volatile` modifier and once without ([example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/load))). I checked the source code of the G++ standard library implementation and I found all of them to be exact duplicates, for example,

```
bool
load(memory_order __m = memory_order_seq_cst) const noexcept
{ return _M_base.load(__m); }

bool
load(memory_order __m = memory_order_seq_cst) const volatile noexcept
{ return _M_base.load(__m); }
```

I could not find any example where the `volatile` variant behaves differently than the non-`volatile` one, differs in return type or anything of that sort.

Why is that? I thought a `volatile` member function could also be called in objects which are not `volatile`. So declaring and defining `std::atomic::load(...) const volatile noexcept` etc. should be enough.

**Update:**

Based on the comments my question basically boils down to: Can you provide an example where some calls using a **non-`volatile`** instance (not necessarily of `std::atomic`) would generate a different assembly in the two following cases,

1. every member function appears with the same body with and without `volatile`,
2. only the `volatile` variant exists?

This, assuming the compiler can do whatever optimization the standard allows it to (or simply highest optimization levels).

Comment: Using `volatile` has its own cost.

Comment: On *the platform you looked at*, they are identical

Comment: @Caleth Would it be a non-conforming implementation if they left the non-volatiles unimplemented and relied on the `volatile` variant to get automatically called?

Comment: @Jarod42 That sounds like it could be it. Do you have a little code to demonstrate this?

Comment: `volatile` force to reload `this` each time its access to it. so 2 consecutive `load` would produce different asm depending of volatile or not.

Comment: @Jarod42 But atomics already do that?

Comment: @PasserBy: I meant `atom.load(); atom.load();` -> (pseudo asm) `read atom; call load; /*read atom;*/ call load;` The second `read atom;` is needed in case of `volatile`.

Comment: @Jarod42 `this` has type `volatile atomic<T>*`, not `atomic<T>* volatile` and doesn't require a reload, if that's what you're getting at.

Comment: @PasserBy: Indeed, it is not `this`, but `*this` which is `volatile`, so `_M_base` need a reload.

Comment: "_I found all of them to be exact duplicates, for example,_" The posted code is **not** an example of "exact duplicates".

Comment: @curiousguy The function body is the same. Of course, now the members etc. are volatile so the generated assembly can differ. Can you elaborate what is the difference it makes? I'm still looking for an answer.

Comment: @TheVee You don't show the declaration of called functions. Are they all volatile?

Comment: @curiousguy I can't find any difference in `__atomic_base` (which is the type of `_M_base`) either: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.1.0/libstdc++/api/a00739_source.html#l00389. The function called from there, `__atomic_load_n`, looks like a built-in, if that encloses the difference I don't know. In the spirit of my update, tests that I have tried showed none so far, but they are far from systematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it all stems from what `volatile` is, for that see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4558031/2228338). As the use-cases are quite slim compare to usual application development, that is why nobody usually cares. I will assume that you do not have any practical scenario where you wondering if you should apply those volatile overloadings. Then I will try to come up with an example where you may need those (do not judge it to be too real).

```
volatile std::sig_atomic_t status = ~SIGINT;
std::atomic<int> shareable(100);

void signal_handler(int signal)
{
  status = signal;
}

// thread 1
  auto old = std::signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);
  std::raise(SIGINT);
  int s = status;
  shareable.store(10, std::memory_order_relaxed);
  std::signal(SIGINT, old);

// thread 2
  int i = shareable.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
```

`memory_order_relaxed` guarantees atomicity and modification order consistency, no side-effects. `volatile` cannot be reordered with side-effects. Then here we are, in thread 2 you can get `shareable` equal 10, but status is still not `SIGINT`. However, if you set type qualifier to `volatile` of `shareable` that must be guaranteed. For that you will need the member methods be `volatile`-qualified.

Why would you do something like this at all? One case, I might think of, is you have some old code that is using old `volatile`-based stuff  and you cannot modify it for one or another reason. Hard to imagine, but I guess that there might be a need to have some kind of guaranteed order between `atomic` and `volatile` inline assembly. The bottom line, IMHO, is that whenever it is possible you can use new atomic library instead of `volatile` objects, in the case there are some `volatile` objects, that you cannot rid of, and you want to use `atomic` objects, then you might need `volatile` qualifier for the `atomic` objects to have proper ordering guarantees, for that you would need overloading.

**UPDATE**

> But if all I wanted was to have atomic types usable as both volatile and non-volatile, why not just implement the former?

```
struct Foo {
    int k;
};

template <typename T>
struct Atomic {
  void store(T desired) volatile { t = desired; }
  T t;
};

int main(int i, char** argv) {
    //error: no viable overloaded '='
    // void store(T desired) volatile { t = desired; }
  Atomic<Foo>().store(Foo());
  return 0;
}
```

The same would be with `load` and other operations, because those are usually not trivial implementations that require copy operator and/or copy constructor (that also can `volatile` or non-`volatile`).

Comment: Sorry, I think I understand the reasoning but not how that explains why both `volatile` and non-`volatile` are needed, with the same body. So the order guarantee would be restored if the `atomic` was also `volatile`, right? But if all I wanted was to have `atomic` types usable as both `volatile` and non-`volatile`, why not just implement the former?

Comment: @TheVee Yes, `volatile atomic` gives you order guarantees . If I correctly understood your second question: `volatile` on members is a specifier to compiler similar to `const`, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4826755/2228338), you have to duplicate implementation due to `atomic` being a class template, you do not want to force all the users force to mark their methods with `volatile` for `MyClass` that is a type of an object member in `atomic<MyClass>`.

Comment: I think the last sentence is exactly what I'm looking for, but I'm still not completely sure. What methods would `MyClass` need to declare as `volatile` if this was not the case? The generic `atomic` provides just a couple operations, effectively just `load`, `store`, and `exchange` plus some porcelain, so perhaps (only) `operator=`?