# What is the best way to implement the stop action for server on interruption signal?

Tags: c++, c++11, server

I am writting a small server with forever loop and I want to have an ability to stop it correctly, for instance, on Ctrl + C (SIGINT).

```
class Server
{
...
public:
  void loop()
  {
    while(_run_flag)
    {
      // do something
    }
  }
  void stop()
  {
    _run_flag = 0;
  }
...
private:
  volatile sig_atomic_t _run_flag = 1;
};

namespace
{
std::function<void()> callback_wrapper;

void signal_handler(int)
{
  callback_wrapper();
}

}

int main()
{
  std::unique_ptr<WSGIServer> server = CreateServer("127.0.0.1", 4009);
  callback_wrapper = [&](){ server->stop(); };

  struct sigaction sigIntHandler;
  sigIntHandler.sa_handler = signal_handler;
  sigemptyset(&sigIntHandler.sa_mask);
  sigIntHandler.sa_flags = 0;
  sigaction(SIGINT, &sigIntHandler, NULL);

  server->loop();

  return 0;
}
```

And I have the following questions:

1. What is the type of `run_flag_variable` I should use? Is using `volatile sig_atomic_t` ok?
2. Is it safe to call `stop` method in `signal_handler`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems almost legit, except I could suggest few improvements. One is not so serious: if you can use C++ only, I mean primitives form `csignal` header, and try to avoid `volatile` we have already `atomic` stuff, more you can read my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51517245/2228338), thought the question is not much relevant. For the second, there are many caveats with what you can and cannot do in signal handlers, C++-14,17 have changed a lot, besides there are some non standards, but platform-specific ways of doing stuff, however the simplest rule is you must use atomic/volatile stuff, if you do not, you must have a good reason and be platform-specific.

```
std::atomic_bool global_run_flag(true);

class Server {
public:
  Server() : _local_run_flag(true) {}

  void loop() {
    while (_local_run_flag && global_run_flag) {
      // do something
    }
  }
  void stop() { _local_run_flag = false; }

private:
  std::atomic_bool _local_run_flag;
};

void signal_handler(int) { global_run_flag = false; }

int main() {
  std::unique_ptr<Server> server(new Server);

  std::signal(SIGINT, &signal_handler);

  server->loop();

  return 0;
}
```

I gave an example how you can track a global condition set from a signal handler, and a local, if you need one, set from other threads, for example.