# Member functions that are volatile and const

Tags: c++, volatile, c++03

I came across this post [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444734/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-volatile-member-function-in-c) which attempts to explain volatile member functions and const volatile member functions. The top answerer stated

> marking a member function as const or volatile (or a combined const
>   volatile) applies those qualifiers to the this pointer used in the
>   function

What does the above mean ?  How does marking the `this` qualifier of a method as volatile or const volatile affect the `this` pointer?

I am confused what that would mean to the method(s) as such

```
class foo
{
   void someMethod() volatile 
   {std::cout << "volatile method" }

   void otherMethod() const volatile 
   {std::cout << "const volatile method"}
};
```

Comment: In your example, you're not referencing `this` (implicitly or explicitly), so the qualifiers have no effect.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Yup. My mistake. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `this` is marked `volatile`, it will affect the compiler's ability to optimise away updates to/from the members pointed to by `*this`.

The TYPICAL use-case for `volatile` is where you have hardware registers - not particularly typical to use a `class` to describe hardware registers, but we can do it.

For example, one could have a class like this:

```
class my_hardware_device
{
  public:
    int32_t reg1; 
    int32_t reg2;
  private:
    int32_t reserved;
  public:
    int32_t reg4;
    int func() volatile;
};

volatile my_hardware_device hw1 = 
   reinterpret_cast<volatile my_hardware_device*>(0x10000000); 
...
int my_hardware_device::func() volatile
{ 
    reg2 = 3;
    reg3 = 8;
    reg2 = 7;
    if (reg2 == 4)
    {
       ...
    }
}

...
hw1->func();
```

Without `volatile`, the compiler could very well decide to remove the `reg2 = 3` and determine that `reg2 == 4` is always false, both because of `reg2 = 7;`. But since it's actually pointing at some hardware, it doesn't behave the way the compiler would expect. [This is a very silly example just constructed to show how it could work - I'm not by any means suggesting that this is a "correct" or "good" solution for any such hardware interface - never mind portability problems, and all manner of other things - and of course the vtable would cause complete havoc if you ever tried to use this with virtual functions - and if you are dealing with hardware in a driver, you probably do want vtables to solve hardware variants, giving yet another reason for implementing this sort of code in a different way.]

The `const` variant means that the compiler is not allowed to write to members of `*this` (in other words members in the class `foo` in your example), except if they are marked as `mutable` (or if a `const_cast` is used to cast away the constness - `const_cast` can also be used to cast away volatileness, by the way).

Combining the both `const` and `volatile` simply means that reads can not be optimised away, and the compiler is not allowed to update the members of `*this`.