# C++ - What does volatile represent when applied to a method?

Tags: c++, volatile

If I have a C++ method declaration as follows:

```
class A
{
public:
   double getPrice() volatile;
};
```

1. What does `volatile` represent here?
2. What could it be used for?

You might be interested in [this](http://www.drdobbs.com/184403766) Dr Dobbs article by Andrei Alexandrescu. I was :)

**Edit:**
That article was written a while back and now it seems that the community has moved on. Herb Sutter has this to say [this](http://herbsutter.com/2009/01/12/effective-concurrency-volatile-vs-volatile/). Thanks Iain (and Herb!)

@metal points out that Andrei had a follow up article [here](http://www.drdobbs.com/184403774) where he continues to advocate the use of volatile correctness as a valuable tool for detecting race conditions on systems supporting POSIX-like mutexes.

Comment: This may be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444695/volatile-vs-mutable-in-c .

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're probably familiar with `const` methods and const-correctness (cf. "Item 15 - Use const proactively" in *[C++ Coding Standards](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321113586)* by Sutter and Alexandrescu), and `volatile` works in similar but slightly different ways to yield what might be called "volatile-correctness."

Like `const`, `volatile` is a type modifier. When attached to a member function as in your example, either modifier (or both!) mean that the object on which the method is called must have or be convertible to that type.

Consider:

```
struct A
{
  void f();
  void cf() const;
  void vf() volatile;
  void cvf() const volatile;
  // ...
};

void foo( A& a, const A& ca, volatile A& va, const volatile A& cva )
{
  a.f();    // Ok
  a.cf();   // Ok: Can convert non-const    obj to const    obj
  a.vf();   // Ok: Can convert non-volatile obj to volatile obj
  a.cvf();  // Ok: Can convert non-cv       obj to cv       obj

  ca.f();   // Error: can't call non-const method on const obj
  ca.cf();  // Ok
  ca.vf();  // Error: can't call non-const method on const obj
  ca.cvf(); // Ok: Can convert

  va.f();   // Error: can't call non-volatile method on volatile obj
  va.cf();  // Error: can't call non-volatile method on volatile obj
  va.vf();  // Ok
  va.cvf(); // Ok: Can convert

  cva.f();   // Error: can't call non-cv method on cv obj
  cva.cf();  // Error: can't call non-cv method on cv obj
  cva.vf();  // Error: can't call non-cv method on cv obj
  cva.cvf(); // Ok
}
```

Note these are compile-time errors, not run-time errors, and that is where it's potential usefulness comes in.

Const-correctness prevents unintentional errors *at compile-time* as well as making code "easier to understand, track, and reason about" (Sutter and Alexandrescu). Volatile-correctness can function similarly but is much less used (note that `const_cast` in C++ can cast away `const`, `volatile`, or `const volatile`, but rather than calling it `cv_cast` or similar, it's named after `const` alone because it is far more commonly used for casting away just `const`).

For instance, in ["volatile - Multithreaded Programmer's Best Friend"](http://www.drdobbs.com/184403766;jsessionid=NIOMCX3NKZF0ZQE1GHPCKH4ATMY32JVN), Andrei Alexandrescu gives some examples of how this can be used to have the compiler automatically detect race conditions in multithreaded code. It has plenty of explanation about how type modifiers work, too, but see also his follow-up comments in his [subsequent column](http://www.drdobbs.com/184403774;jsessionid=RWBZ1W2RDBPBLQE1GHPCKH4ATMY32JVN).

---

*Update*:

Note that C++11 changes the meaning of `const`. [Thus sayeth the Sutter](https://herbsutter.com/2013/05/24/gotw-6a-const-correctness-part-1-3/): "`const` now really does mean 'read-only, or safe to read concurrently'—either truly physically/bitwise `const`, or internally synchronized so that any actual writes are synchronized with any possible concurrent `const` accesses so the callers can’t tell the difference."

Elsewhere, [he notes](https://herbsutter.com/2014/01/13/gotw-95-solution-thread-safety-and-synchronization/) that while C++11 has added concurrency primitives, `volatile` is still not one of them: "C++ volatile variables (which have no analog in languages like C# and Java) are always beyond the scope of this and any other article about the memory model and synchronization. That’s because C++ volatile variables aren’t about threads or communication at all and don’t interact with those things. Rather, a C++ volatile variable should be viewed as portal into a different universe beyond the language — a memory location that by definition does not obey the language’s memory model because that memory location is accessed by hardware (e.g., written to by a daughter card), have more than one address, or is otherwise 'strange' and beyond the language. So C++ volatile variables are universally an exception to every guideline about synchronization because are always inherently “racy” and unsynchronizable using the normal tools (mutexes, atomics, etc.) and more generally exist outside all normal of the language and compiler including that they generally cannot be optimized by the compiler.... For more discussion, see my article '[volatile vs. volatile](http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/volatile-vs-volatile/212701484).'"

Comment: Thanks for the link to the subsequent column. I have edited my question to include it.

Answer (score 12):

It is a volatile member which, just like a const member can only be called on const objects, can only be called on volatile objects.

What's the use?  Well, globally volatile is of little use (it is often misunderstood to be applicable for multi-threaded -- MT -- programming, it isn't the case in C++, see for instance http://www.drdobbs.com/high-performance-computing/212701484), and volatile class objects are even less useful.

IIRC A. Alexandrescu has proposed to use the type checking done on volatile objects to statically ensure some properties usefull for MT programming (say that a lock has been taken before calling a member function).  Sadly, I don't find the article back. (Here it is: http://www.drdobbs.com/184403766)

Edit: added links from the comments (they where added also in the question).

Comment: Do you know of any good resources on why `volatile` shouldn't be used for MT?

Comment: I edited my question to include the article by Andrei to which you refer. I wrote this question in response to a previous question about const by another member and thought this question would be good follow on

Comment: Papers about the memory model by Boehm and others on the committee site describe this.

Comment: @Pedro re volatile and MT see http://herbsutter.com/2009/01/12/effective-concurrency-volatile-vs-volatile/

Comment: @T33C, it is so old?  Time flies.  Note that Andrei mention in this article that volatile per se is related to threads.  I don't think he would now.

Comment: Herb's paper pointed by iain is in line with my understanding.

Comment: I am unable to read Herb's article. Work proxy filters it. Thanks for all the comments. I was blown away by Andrei's article because I had never considered a volatile method.

Comment: @T33C, the blog is mostly to refer to: http://www.drdobbs.com/high-performance-computing/212701484

Comment: The Alexandrescu article is at: http://www.ddj.com/cpp/184403766;jsessionid=URZPZDHYE0HWLQE1GHOSKHWATMY32JVN

Comment: Thanks for the interesting comments everyone. Because this answer led to the comments I am selecting it as the answer plus it got the most votes.

Comment: IMO it would make sense if `volatile` would prevent method from being inlined. I really miss counterpart to `inline`.

Comment: Since this is the accepted answer, I'd suggest at first use of the acronym "MT" be spelled out as "Multi Threaded (MT)". A google search for "MT programming" gives no hint to one unfamiliar with the acronym in this context.

Comment: @erco, you can edit the answer, that's the stackoverflow way.

Answer (score 5):

In member functions (the only functions that can have cv-qualifiers), the `const` or `volatile` effectively modifies the `this` pointer.  Therefore, like a `const` member function can access the object only as if through a `const` pointer, a `volatile` member function can access the object only as if through a `volatile` pointer.

The informal meaning of `volatile` is that an object can change due to circumstances outside the program (such as memory-mapped I/O or shared memory).  The precise meaning is that any access to `volatile` data must be done in reality as it is written in the code, and may not be optimized out or changed in order relative to other `volatile` accesses or I/O operations.

What this means is that any operations relating to the object in `volatile` member functions must be done in order as written.

Further, a `volatile` member function can only call other `volatile` (or `const volatile`) member functions.

As for what use it is...frankly, I can't think of a good use right now.  `volatile` is vital for some data objects, such as pointers pointed to I/O registers, but I can't think of why a `volatile` member function would be useful.